# j-query date-picker does not work after post back

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a j-query date-picker that does not work after the first post back.  It only works before the post back but the date-picker does not work after post back.  the text-box that shows the date-picker is wrapped with ajax update panel.  here is my j-query:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.date-picker').mousedown(function () {

            $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: After postback you have to reinitialize the jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that on a partial post back, which is what happens when an `UpdatePanel` causes a post back, the DOM is not reloaded and thus your `$().ready(function () {` will not fire and wire up the date picker. This is one of those ASP.NET AJAX gotchas.

One way to deal with this is to have a JavaScript function invoked when the `PageRequestManager` does the partial post back via the `UpdatePanel`, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.date-picker').mousedown(function () {

            $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy',
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            });
        });
    });

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function() {
        // Re-bind your jQuery objects here

    });
</script>
```

> Note: This is one of those places where jQuery and ASP.NET AJAX do not play nice without a little tweaking.

Comment: thanks Karl, i really don't much about jquery but what you mean when you say Re bind your jquery?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a rebind for every page load like this :

```
 function pageLoad() {
     $('#mydatepick').unbind();
     $('#mydatepick').datepicker();
 };
```